# Есть слайдер на bootstrap. Не работают кнопки перехода влево-вправо, сделанные в виде картинок 80*80 пикселей

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, слайдер

```
<section style="width: 500px">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/spec/1.jpeg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>раз</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/spec/1.jpeg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>два</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/spec/1.jpeg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>три</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <img src="img/34.png">
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
            <img src="img/35.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Все работает корректно , проверил
`https://jsfiddle.net/powertimka/d53g389y/1/`

Какая версия bootstrap ?

Comment: @ТимофейСеменюк 3.3.7, как и у вас. Что-то не ладится всё равно.

Comment: в консоле при клике ошибок нету и вообще нету ошибок ?

Comment: @ТимофейСеменюк миллион ошибок... http://www.lesha.wemakesites.ru/ вот тут валяется.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Подключите Jquery перед bootstrap.min.js

Точнее у вас не правильно он подключен `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Это из консоли ошибок вашего сайта

Comment: подключил по-новому, ошибка ушла, но я всё равно не могу листать слайдер кнопками, только в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: @lesha_ber,вставил код из jsfiddle в ваш сайт , все работает , попробуйте вставить его и отталкиваться от него,хоть и не вижу в них различий особых